# Footer inside content div (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

My footer gets stuck in the content div

Code https://jsfiddle.net/rfh7jomp/

Tried position:relative;, but then it wont be in the bottom in smaller pages.

Using the bootstrap if that matters.

*HTML Code*:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
         <p>footer text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS Code*:

```
.footer
{
    position: absolute;
    clear:both;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(111, 111, 111, 0.65);
    border-top:1px solid #bbb;
    color:#F3F3F3;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed;` is maybe the solution you're looking for ?

Comment: It doesn't help that much. Instead of getting stuck on the middle, then it's stuck on the bottom http://puu.sh/kmzeu/87fcb6d563.jpg.

Changing the padding/margin won't move it further down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.2.0, just add class `navbar-fixed-bottom` to your `footer` class,and remove `position: absolute;` from `.footer`

demo--> https://jsfiddle.net/rfh7jomp/2/

Answer (score 0):

I found two usefull ways. One is adding class navbar-fixed-bottom (as in previous answer), and two is adding a sticky foooter, as bootstrap itself recommends (link here):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/

open the page, copy the content associated to the footer, and copy the css codes in the link sticky-footer.css

One last thing is that I errase the codes associates to container class in sticky-footer.css becuase I was having issues with them.

My css code resulted this way:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```